# Shortcut to look up a word from a document on a specific website

Tags: osx-lion, search, shortcuts

On my MacOsX 10.7 (Lion), I would like to be able to select a word in a document, program or webpage and use it as an input for the search-fonction on a specific website. I know this function is available for Google and Wikipedia (right-click, "Writing Tools", "Search on Google" or "Search on Wikipedia"), but I would like to use it on another website.

As a medical student, I often encounter names of medications of which I don't exactly know what the side-effects are, so I have to look them up on "www.bcfi.be" ('cause I'm from Belgium). The website-URL after a search like that looks like this: http://www.bcfi.be/search/search.cfm?zone=R&zoekterm=haloperidol (I looked up "haloperidol").

I am a complete noob when it comes to programming, so I have no idea how or where to begin...

Answer (score 0):

These search shortcuts come from Spotlight. The search engine used in "Search on ...", is the one that is set as default in Safari. Unfortunately only Google, Yahoo and Bing are supported.